# open xterm with allow-send-events set to True

Tags: events, terminal, arguments, debian, xterm

I would like to open xterm from a terminal with the command

> xterm

and specify the [parameter](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm)

> allow-send-events(toggle)

set to true (without having to do ctrl+click and set it to True manually once xterm is open)

Yet, reading through the term documentation I can't figure out what argument I have to specify to do this. Could someone kindly point it out?

**EDIT**

I would also be happy if there is a way to toggle this setting directly in the xterm with a typed command e.g.

> xterm > allow-send-events("ON")

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command sets the resource [allowSendEvents](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:allowSendEvents) when starting xterm:

```
xterm -xrm '*allowSendEvents:true'
```

There also is a [menu entry](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Main-Options:Allow-SendEvents) (control-button-one shows the menu).

Comment: Thank you, this works for regular xterm usage- Just an FYI for posterity: unfortunately summoning the xterm for a [mininet](http://mininet.org/) host through the mininet CLI, does not seem to recognise parameters. It only reads hostnames and throws away the specified parameters, therefore opening the default xterm every time.